# How to make my brownies rise?

Tags: brownies, rising

My brownies always end up the same size after cooking as they were at the beginning, even though they rise by 100% during preparation. How can I keep them from sinking when they cook? The recipe:

- 375 g chocolate with milk
- 350 g butter

I melt those and let them chill.

In another bowl I mix for a long time:

- 4 eggs
- 380 g of sugar

Then add the chocolate and butter, mix a lot again and add:

- 130 g regular flour
- 90 g of sweet cocoa
- 5 g of rising powder.

Again I beat in a lot of air but even though they rise, they come out exactly as they entered the oven.

Comment: Related question with the opposite problem: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18391/25818

Comment: My gut reaction looking at your ingredient list is that is an awful lot of fat in the recipe.

Comment: That seems like quite a lot of egg.  You might get fudgier (but not higher-rising) brownies by using 3, or even 2, eggs.  Generally the more eggs you add the more cake-like (and less brownie-like!) your brownies will become.

Comment: What do you mean by "they rise during preparation"?

Comment: What do you mean by rising powder? Do you mean baking powder or baking soda (sodium bicarbonate or bicarb)?

Comment: Agreed rising powder could mean a few different things all of which react differently depending on your other ingredients or techniques. Baking powder generally will cause more rise than baking soda for example, but only if you mix it and get it in the oven right away. You don't let it sit to rise in the counter first.

Comment: Since the question says "they come out exactly as they entered the oven," I'm assuming the "rising during preparation" must be referring to rising *while baking*.  It's a common problem for baked goods to rise high but then fall while baking.  This usually has to do with the gluten structure being unable to support the weight and/or too much gas being released so bubbles get big and pop out the top of the batter before the structure sets.

Answer (score 1):

Try 3 eggs instead. I know that on the back of brownie mixes, it states "to make cake like brownies add 2 eggs, for fudge like add 3 eggs"